# Managing project in LAN network

Tags: tasks, tracking, task-management, software

I'm managing a project in my company, and we have **many tasks** that should be **assigned to many employees** and then be **tracked**.

We use telephone communication, e-mails and even face to face communications, but we fail to efficiently communicate or even track progress in each task.

I decided to download some software that makes us able to communicate, share files and folders, list tasks, assign tasks to people and track progress in these tasks.

BUT the company *doesn't allow us to share files over the internet*, so we are searching for a **LAN-network project management software**, is there such a thing? free or paid.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PMSE. Unfortunately you are asking for a software recommendation, what is out of topic here. Check the [tour] site for more information. Maybe you want to ask your question in the Software recommendations SE?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are tools that can be used, however I would suggest that before you try to obtain something, you think about how you would want to use such a tool. If you are the PM, do you need other people to be updating a tool? or would you prefer to communicate with them directly then you update the tool yourself? (I am not saying one is right and one is wrong - although I would personally be reluctant to let other people record progress on my project... that's my job, and while I am reasonably trusting, I want to validate anything that goes into my records!)

So, what I am saying is this. Before looking for a tool, first think about your use cases for it, then decide whether you still need such a tool, and if you do, what features / capabilities you require. I appreciate that this does not answer your question, however it may encourage you to look at the requirement from a different perspective and thereby remove the need for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Use that same software but restrict it to your company intranet

You can use whatever software that you were planning to download and use over the public internet. However, restrict its access to your company intranet. That should meet the security needs of your company.

From the [Wikipedia entry on Intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet):

> Increasingly, intranets are being used to deliver tools, e.g.
>   collaboration (to facilitate working in groups and teleconferencing)
>   or sophisticated corporate directories, sales and customer
>   relationship management tools, project management etc., to advance
>   productivity.